# TouchImageView background not refreshed on GalaxyTab 8.9 Android V3.1

Tags: android, galaxy-tab

I'm working on a modified version of TouchImageView ( https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView ).

It's working fine on all devices and emulators, but it's not working properly on GalaxyTab 8.9. The background around the zoomable image is not redrawn.

You can see the problem on this video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxa6I3wzYrw

I've tried to :

- call setBackgroundColor(0xff00ff00) on the parent view of TouchImageView, background is red as expected, but the problem is still here.
- call invalidate regularly on the parent view of the TouchImageView, nothing changed.
- build a sample project with only one activity and the TouchImageView and the same problems happens

There are still a lot of things to try, but this will be so time consuming to try everything. Would like to hear a few ideas to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug seen on Android tablets (seen on Samsung galaxy tab, Nexus 7)
A workaround is to invalidate a top view in the hierarchy (invalidating the parent view of the TouchImageView is not enough to fix it)

Comment: Do you know more about the bug that you're mentioning here? A link to the official issue thread or any forum that has details on how to reproduce this should help. Thanks